# clearTimeout function does not run

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cleartimeout

I've made a quiz game using socket.io. When a new socket connects, this runs:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
let gameTimer = null;
```

After receiving a certain socket from the client, this function starts:

```
gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
//Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

//Start the countdown for the next question
countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);
}, 21000)
```

When a player answers, this socket function runs in the server:

```
socket.on('Answered Question', function (userAnswer, answeredPlayerUsername, timeAnswered) {
//Stop the count
clearTimeout(gameTimer);

/*
*Extra code below that works...
*/
```

But this does not stop the timeout. Any reason why this is happening, and how to fix it?

EDIT: Here's the full socket code. It's a bit long, apologies:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('Someone connected');

    //Will hold the questions used for the session
    let gameSessionQuestions = null;

    //Holds the current question
    let currentQuestion = null;

    //Holds the correct answer to the current question
    let currentQuestionAnswer = null;

    //Give the socket player details
    //and add this player to the dictionary
    playerData[socket.id] = {
        name: null,
        room: null,
        host: false,
        score: 0
    };

    //Timer for questions
    let gameTimer = null;


    /*
    SOCKET OPERATIONS
    */

    socket.on('Get Total Score', async function(playerUsername){
        let playerTotalScore = await gameController.getTotalScore(playerUsername);
        socket.emit('Receive Total Score', playerTotalScore); 
    })


    //Adds a room to the list of rooms
    socket.on('Add Room', function (questionType) {
        let newRoom = newRoomCreation(questionType);

        //Since this player created the room, assign them the host value
        playerData[socket.id].host = true;
        playerData[socket.id].room = newRoom;

        socket.join(newRoom);

        io.sockets.to(newRoom).emit('Room Added', newRoom);

    })

    //Make the specified room a closed room
    socket.on('Close the room', function (room) {
        closeRoom(room);
    })

    socket.on('Room Availability', function (roomCode, questionType) {

        if (!roomMap.get(roomCode)) {
            socket.emit('Unavailable Room');
        }
        else {
            //Check if the room has the question type the user chose
            if (roomQuestionType.get(roomCode) == questionType) {
                socket.emit('Available Room');
            } else {
                socket.emit('Unavailable Room');
            }

        }

    })

    socket.on('Open Room Availability', function (questionType) {
        let roomFound = false;

        for (let room of roomMap.keys()) {
            if (!closedRoomsList.includes(room)) {
                if (roomQuestionType.get(room) == questionType) {
                    roomFound = true;
                    socket.emit('Available Open Room', room);
                }
            }
        }

        if (roomFound == false) {
            socket.emit('Unavailable Open Room');
        }


    })

    socket.on('Join Room', function (values) {

        //Give this player's 'name' variable a value
        playerData[socket.id].name = values.p1;

        //Give this player's 'room' variable a value
        playerData[socket.id].room = values.p2;

        //DELETE SOON: Checking the data before addition
        console.log("Data in the room '" + values.p2 + "' before addition: ");
        console.log(roomMap.get(values.p2));

        //Put this player in the new room
        socket.join(values.p2);

        //Add the player's socketID and Name to the Room Map
        let playersList = roomMap.get(values.p2);
        playersList.push(values.p1);


        //DELETE SOON: Checking the data after addition
        console.log("Data in the room '" + values.p2 + "' after addition: ");
        console.log(roomMap.get(values.p2));

        io.sockets.to(values.p2).emit('Output Players', playersList);

        if (playerData[socket.id].host == true) {
            io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Current Host');
        }
    })

    socket.on('Request Game Start', async function (room) {

        //Checks if the user who started the game truly is the host
        if (playerData[socket.id].host == false) {
            return;
        }

        //Holds all the questions to be asked and their answers
        gameSessionQuestions = await selectedQuestions(2, roomQuestionType.get(room));

        //Reset the 'answered player' count
        answeredPlayers.set(playerData[socket.id].room, 0);

        io.sockets.to(room).emit('Game Start');
    })

    socket.on('Start Game Countdown', function () {

        let pos = 0;
        let countArr = ["2", "1", "Go"];

        let counter = setInterval(function () {
            //Update the count for all those in the room
            io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Update Countdown', countArr[pos]);


            if (pos == countArr.length) {
                clearInterval(counter);

                io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('End Countdown');

                currentQuestion = getQuestion(gameSessionQuestions[0], playerData[socket.id].room);

                io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Receive Questions', currentQuestion);

                //Holds the answer for the current question
                currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestionCorrectAnswer(gameSessionQuestions[0], playerData[socket.id].room);

                //The answer to the question presented in this room is stored here
                questionAnswers.set(playerData[socket.id].room, currentQuestionAnswer);

                gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    //Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
                    revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

                    //Start the countdown for the next question
                    countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);
                }, 21000)

            } else {
                pos++;
            }

        }, 1000);
    })

    socket.on('Answered Question', function (userAnswer, answeredPlayerUsername, timeAnswered) {

        socket.broadcast.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Display Answered Player', answeredPlayerUsername);

        //DELETE SOON: Check the current question
        console.log("Current Question's Answer: " + questionAnswers.get(playerData[socket.id].room));
        console.log("Your answer: " + userAnswer);

        let answerResult;

        if (questionAnswers.get(playerData[socket.id].room) === userAnswer) {
            answerResult = "btn-success";

            //Add to the person's overall score
            playerData[socket.id].score = addToScore(playerData[socket.id].score, timeAnswered);

            socket.emit('Answer Check', answerResult);

        }
        else {
            answerResult = "btn-danger";
            socket.emit('Answer Check', answerResult);
        }

        //DELETE SOON: Checks the scores for the user
        console.log("The score for '" + playerData[socket.id].name + "' is '" + playerData[socket.id].score + "'")

        //Add 1 to the number of people who have answered in this room
        answeredPlayers.set(playerData[socket.id].room, (answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room)) + 1)

        //DELETE SOON: Checks if the value is updating
        console.log("Number of people who have answered: " + answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room))

        //If all users in the room have answered...
        if (answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room) == (roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room)).length) {

            //DELETE SOON: Outputs message confirming all users answering
            console.log("Everyone has answered");

            //Stop the count
            clearTimeout(gameTimer);

            //Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
            revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

            //Start the countdown for the next question
            countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);

        }
    })

    //Get the next question from the host
    socket.on('Find Host', async function () {

        if (playerData[socket.id].host == true) {

            //DELETE SOON: Check the number of questions before
            console.log('Question count before: ' + gameSessionQuestions.length)

            gameSessionQuestions.shift();

            //DELETE SOON: Check the number of questions after removing the one just asked
            console.log('Question count after: ' + gameSessionQuestions.length)

            //If there are still questions to be asked, send the next question and set the new correct answer
            if (gameSessionQuestions.length != 0) {

                //Get the next question and send it
                currentQuestion = getQuestion(gameSessionQuestions[0], playerData[socket.id].room);
                io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Receive Questions', currentQuestion);

                //Get this question's correct answer
                currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestionCorrectAnswer(gameSessionQuestions[0], playerData[socket.id].room);
                questionAnswers.set(playerData[socket.id].room, currentQuestionAnswer);

                gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    //Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
                    revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

                    //Start the countdown for the next question
                    countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);
                }, 21000)

            } else {

                //Holds the username and scores for all users in this room
                let players_Scores = [];

                let roomCode = playerData[socket.id].room;

                let playerKeys = Object.keys(playerData);

                for (let i = 0; i < playerKeys.length; i++) {
                    if (playerData[playerKeys[i]].room == roomCode) {

                        let scoreDetails = {
                            username: playerData[playerKeys[i]].name,
                            score: playerData[playerKeys[i]].score
                        }

                        players_Scores.push(scoreDetails)

                        await gameController.uploadScore(playerData[playerKeys[i]].name, playerData[playerKeys[i]].score, roomQuestionType.get(roomCode));
                    }
                }

                io.sockets.to(roomCode).emit('Show Scores', players_Scores);

            }
        }

    })

    //Remove details while reloading the menu page
    socket.on('Back to Start', function () {

        //Remove the player from the room in socketio
        socket.leave(playerData[socket.id].room);

        //If this is the host, delete the room
        if (playerData[socket.id].host == true) {
            roomMap.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
            roomQuestionType.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
            questionAnswers.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
            answeredPlayers.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
        }

        //Remove this player's details
        delete playerData[socket.id];

    })

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {

        if (playerData[socket.id] && roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room) != undefined) {
            //DELETE SOON: Check who left and from which room
            console.log(playerData[socket.id].name + " has left the room '" + playerData[socket.id].room + "'");

            //If on the lobby page, remove that player and update everyone's lists
            let playerList = roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room);
            playerList.splice(playerList.indexOf(playerData[socket.id].name), 1);

            io.sockets.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Output Players', playerList);

            /*If this is the host,
            * stop game timer
            * alert all the players in the room,
            * delete the room they were in*/
            if (playerData[socket.id].host == true) {
                clearTimeout(gameTimer);

                socket.broadcast.to(playerData[socket.id].room).emit('Host Left');
                roomMap.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
                roomQuestionType.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
                questionAnswers.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
                answeredPlayers.delete(playerData[socket.id].room);
            }

            delete playerData[socket.id];
        }

    })

})
```

Comment: Post all the code together, hard to tell with small chunks scattered around

Comment: No problem. I have added the full "io.on('connection', function(){})" code. It is a bit long. my apologies. Let me know if you need to see the code for some of the functions.

Comment: `let counter = setInterval(function () { ..... gameTimer = setTimeout(function () { ....{)` um, you could create multiple timeouts. So when you call clear, it will only ever clear the last one.

Comment: I think you need to define `gameTimer` outside the scope of your `on('connect')` function

Comment: @GlennFerrie I was thinking of doing that. Will try that out now.

Comment: @YawZing6 have you explored Web Workers? It's a modern approach to handling asynchronous workloads.  more info from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @GlennFerrie No I have not. I will check it out. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @epascarello i'm a bit confused.

Comment: @GlennFerrie It unfortunately did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in the smallest code to rep

```js
let gameTimer;
let pos = 0;
let countArr = ["2", "1", "Go"];

let counter = setInterval(function () {
  if (pos == countArr.length) {
    console.log("Creating a new gameTimer", Date.now());
    gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('gameTimer executed')
    }, 2100);
  } else {
    pos++;
  }
}, 1000);
```

So your code keeps creating new timeouts. The previous timeouts exist, they do not get removed.

So you need to either remove the gameTimer before you create a new one, or do not create gameTimer if it is already running

```js
let gameTimer;
let pos = 0;
let countArr = ["2", "1", "Go"];

let counter = setInterval(function () {
  if (pos == countArr.length) {
    if (gameTimer) return; // if gameTimer is defined, exit
    console.log("Creating a new gameTimer", Date.now());
    gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('gameTimer executed')
    }, 2100);
  } else {
    pos++;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ooooooooooooh, i see. Thank you very much. Gonna edit that now

Comment: While this makes a lot of sense to me, it seems that the main issue with my code is that the gametimer isn't being stopped in later parts of the code when "ClearTimeout(gameTimer)" is called, specifically at the "Answered Question" socket function

Comment: Well if you have a bunch of timers, the `clearTimeout(gameTimer)` will only cancel the last one that you registered. So did you make it so you do not create multiple gameTimers?

Comment: Okay yeah that makes a lot of sense, haha. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at my code again, I did put in a clearInterval() after the ```if (pos == countArr.length) {``` line, which does indeed stop it from repeating(I checked). Any other possible reason why I cannot stop the Timeout?

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be an error when accessing the variable, but without the entire code, it is not viable.

Comment: I have added the full "io.on('connection', function(){})" code. It is a bit long. my apologies. Let me know if you need to see the code for some of the functions.